# How can I bring a register only if it doesn't contains a string - SQL?

Tags: sql

My query is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%Mary%"
```

But now, I want bring all the occurrences as long as it's not contains "Jane" especially in "Mary". I do not want "Mary Jane", neither "Jane Mary" or any variation (e.g. "Mary Smith Jane").

I really don't know how to.

EDIT: 
I'm not sure if I can only use a "not like" because I'm already using "not like" in the same query for other reasons.

In fact:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name NOT LIKE "%John%"
AND name NOT LIKE '%Charlie%'
AND name LIKE '%Mary%'
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IS LIKE "%Mary%" AND name <> "Mary Jane"`?

Answer (score 1):

Just add that to the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%Mary%' AND
      name NOT LIKE '%Mary Jane%'
```

Or, if you mean that the exact match is not what you want:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%Mary%' AND
      name <> 'Mary Jane'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM your_table  
 WHERE name LIKE '%Mary%' 
   and name <> 'Mary Jane'
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve records that contain Mary in the string, but not Jane, you will want to keep your clause for `LIKE '%Mary%'` and add a clause for `NOT LIKE '%Jane%'`.

You can group these clauses together with parenthesis in order to isolate them from other clauses in the query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
    (name LIKE '%Mary%'
    AND name NOT LIKE '%Jane%')
```